# What is a good packaging when importing green beans to a temperate climate?

Tags: green-coffee, packaging

Importing green beans matters to bring great quality to the cup. But the beans travel from their native mountains in the Green Belt to various climates. What packaging is best when transporting to a temperate climate ("real seasons", a bit of everything, from sun to rain to snow, and negative to positive temperatures).

Packaging could be with traditional hemp bags, with plastic bags, with bacteria-protecting bags, etc. I heard some stories of hemp-packed beans contaminated by animals when transporting by boat. In the past, I have imported hundreds kilos by plane in regulated atmosphere, for best quality, but it may be overdoing it (the beans where quite expensive). All in all, I guess it depends on the kind of beans and transportation.

Comment: Green coffee often sweats when being transported by ship. I've seen more that myt fair share of moldy beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that is air tight would be best. Grain pro, ziplock, etc..
Vacuum packing is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

If the beans are green and dry they can be transported in burlap sacks. But you have to insure that the shipping process can maintain dry conditions. So it is best to use a good quality zip lock bag or vacuum seal the beans after insuring they were complety dry prior to placement in the bags and or sealing.